# Match parent constraint layout not matched

Tags: android, xml

I make a `constraintlayout` match parent but it isn't matched i want when i type large text it goese under the `veiw` not behind supposed my parent `textveiw1`.

[image]

Comment: please post your xml code

Answer (score 2):

`ConstraintLayout` does not use `match_parent`.

To act as `match_parent`, you have to give constraints.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

This will make this `TextView` `match_parent` since all of its 4 sides are constrained to the parent.

`parent` of a `View` indicates the `View` that is surrounding it.

In this case, xml will look like

```
<ConstraintLayout>
    <TextView/>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

So `parent` of this `TextView` is `ConstraintLayout`.

`layout_constraintStart_toStrartOf` is constraining the `TextView` to match it's left(start) to its parent(`ConstraintLayout`)'s left(start).

By applying these constraints to 4 sides of a view(start, end, top, bottom), we can implement `match_parent`.

Comment: i will try it and inform you but if you please when i type parent that mean the layout i constraint with ?

Comment: @NouraAbdelnoor I've added some explanation to my answer.